# openMP number of threads is higher than asked for

Tags: openmp

I'm implementing an openMP version of a sequential program, and for a function that distributes a list for the threads, I need function to know the number of threads.

Boiled down, the code looks like this:

```
int numberOfThreads = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    //split nodeQueue
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

    #pragma omp master
    {
        cout << "Asked for " << NUM_THREADS << endl;
        numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        cout << "Got " << numberOfThreads << " threads" << endl;
        splitNodeQueue(numberOfThreads);
    }
}
```

No matter what I set NUM_THREADS to, it seems to get 4 threads, and outputs:

```
Asked for 1
Got 4 threads
```

Shouln't it get a maximum of NUM_THREADS when I use omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS)?

It doesn't matter what number of threads I ask for - it always gets 4 (which is the number of threads available on the CPU)...

Can't I force it to use the specified number of threads as maximum?

Comment: Where is NUM_THREADS defined?

Comment: At the top 

    #define NUM_THREADS 1

Comment: And it does ASK for the right number of threads set by the definition, but it gets 4 no matter what...

Comment: Try setting the number of threads before entering the parallel region.  I don't think that all current (or recent) implementations of OpenMP support dynamic setting of thread numbers inside already-instantiated parallel regions.

Comment: YES! That was it! I thought it needed to be declared at the beginning of the parallel region... I guess I was wrong. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: The number of threads is an ICV (internal control variable) and **must** be set before entering the parallel region. You could also apply the `num_threads` to the `parallel` directive, e.g. `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, no OpenMP implementation supports this since according to the standard, calling `omp_set_num_threads()` sets the _nthreads-var_ ICV for the current task, which affects the number of threads used for **subsequent** parallel regions forked from within the task.

Answer (score 0):

I think, setting `num_threads` from within parallel region would not change the number of threads for the fork at the start of the parallel region, it only changes the number of threads for nested parallel regions, which defaults to 1 by OMP specs